# Caching strategy - how to cache data from a third party

Tags: caching, redis

So i have a set of data, that can be used in multiple ways coming from a third party. Currently their API isnt very good, the service isnt performant.

And what i was thinking was caching their response since it doesn't change often once a week, the question im facing is, how do i cache? in terms of the data it's used in different contexts and different pieces of data is required each time.

Example

I have a list of cars(make, model. engine size), these cars could be requested either by make, model, engine size.

I can use redis to cache the data and then create a service in front that can periodically update the cache using one of the following approached:

I could keep the cache with the data duplicated, for instance i could keep a cache of car data grouped by make, and another set of data cached thats grouped by size. There is data duplication in the cache. But does it matter?

OR i could just cache the whole set of data, and have the service in front do the processing each time, whena. grouped set of data is requested process the data and extract the group?

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Cars grouped by make are not the same as cars grouped by size. They are un-equivalent relations.

If you reuse these again and again, then it makes sense to cache them both.

Yet, caching the entire table defeats the purpose of having a table in the first place. The reason as of why you use a database table is to allow you to search efficiently. If you duplicate the entire table, then you lose all the benefits of your database management system and you are on your own.

If you have 100 000 000 records in the cars table, you still have a very limited number of make and size and it makes sense to cache groups based on these aggregation criteria, along with other aggregated fields.

Ask yourself: is it the same to know how many people are, say, Africans as knowing how many people are of, say, 1.75 - 1.80 meters? Of course not. Even though the data source is similar, the relations you generate from them via aggregation is different.